# VS Code "Debug Test" of Test Explorer Showing 0/0 Test Results

Tags: pytest, vscode-debugger

I'm encountering an issue with VS Code's Test Explorer when running a simple Python test case.
When I execute the "Debug Test" option, the test result always shows 0/0, indicating that no tests have been run.
However, if I use the "Run Test" option, I get the expected 1/1 result.
This issue occurs across different environments, including macOS, a Docker container running Debian, and Windows 11 in Parallels.

Here's the test case:

```py
from subprocess import run
from sys import executable as python


def test0():
    run([python, "-c", "exit(0)"])
```

What could be causing the Test Explorer's "Debug Test" to not properly execute or recognize the test in these environments?
Are there specific configurations or settings in VS Code that I need to adjust to resolve this issue?